# How can I get the calling method which inherit from other package

Tags: perl

I want to get the calling method's name. I try caller, it works fine in most cases. But the result is not what I expected when the method inherit from parent package. Following is the example:

```
package Caller;
sub output_caller { #output the calling method's name
    my @stacks = caller(1);
    print $stacks[3];
}

package Foo;
sub foo {
    Caller::output_caller();
}

package Bar;
use base 'Foo';

Bar->foo();
```

---

The output is

```
Foo::foo
```

which I expected is

```
Bar::foo
```

Is it possible to get Bar::foo?

Comment: `Bar` is a subclass of `Foo`, so it inherits the method `Foo::foo`. `Bar` itself does not provide a method of that name. Calling a method searches for a method with that name in the class and all parent classes (during runtime). Specifying an ISA relationship does not import methods from parent classes into your class. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: I just need to output some debug message with the method name.It maybe confused if the debug message is "blablabla when you call Foo::foo on line 5" when I actully call Bar::foo on line 5.

Comment: Even if you call `Bar::foo`, the code being run is `Foo::foo`. If you go looking for `Bar::foo` to debug it, you won't find any code there, so I would think Perl's current behavior is more likely to be useful. If you need to know the type of the object the method was called on, `print ref $self`.

Comment: Well *in just this case*, ``$_[0]`` contains what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

`use Carp qw(confess)` gets you close.   It will return

```
at C:\src_test\perl\TestMost\CallerTest.pl line 11.
    Foo::foo('Bar') called at C:\src_test\perl\TestMost\CallerTest.pl line 18
Foo::foo
```

From this modified script

```
package Caller;
sub output_caller { #output the calling method's name
    my @stacks = caller(1);
    print $stacks[3];
}

package Foo;
use Carp qw(cluck);
sub foo {
    cluck();
    Caller::output_caller();
}

package Bar;
use base 'Foo';

Bar->foo();
```